# GWT performance issue with IE

Tags: java, gwt

I have GWT application which in IE8/9 (any version) it perform very poor which means it takes so long time to display records. But in Firefox it shows the result quickly.

I use fiddler and check whether any problem with application side, but the fiddler shows it received the response in 8s. The problem is in IE even those the post request shows finish in fiddler, the browser wont display the result but it shows please wait message for so long like 4 minutes and then display the result. On the other hand Firefox display the records just after the response received in 8s.

This is a grid kind of table with only few records like 60 and use panels in GWT.

Any one face such situation?

Answer (score 0):

A server response of 8 seconds seems very high, probably you are getting a huge response.

For rendering such as amount of data, gwt tables and panels could not be very convenient in IE, so you should consider to use gwt [CellTables](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable) which provides a high-performance rendering.  think you should consider as well to paginate your data using [AsyncDataProvider](http://www.mytechtip.com/2010/11/gwt-celltable-example-using_8168.html)